# If crossing over can cause formation of new allele, can it affect Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium?

Tags: population-genetics, hardy-weinberg, crossover

I was reading about Hardy-Wienberg equilibrium on Wikipedia  and there are **seven assumptions underlying HW**

[image]

It is mentioned that sexual reproduction one of the assumption and is a must for HW, but according to some answers given here on Biology STack exchange crossing over in sexual reproduction can result in exon shuffling
[here is the answer I am referring to](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43119/65724)

so my question is-
**1.can  exon shuffling  cause a new allele to appear in the population?**

**2. If a new allele can appear in the population during the cross over or due to crossing over as it is a random process that will surely change the allelic frequency so how can be sexual reproduction can be a underlying assumption for HW? it should be in the list of things that can affect Hardy-Wienberg like mutation and sexual selection**

**3. Does in majority of cases crossing over only causes reshuffling of allele but not the formation of a new allele? is mutation by crossing over is rare?**

**4. Can Independent assortment and Linkage have any effect on Hardy Weinberg law?**

Comment: I'd consider creation of a new allele by intragenic crossing over a mutation.  HW was developed over 100 years ago, before the molecular nature of the gene was known, so it was based on Mendelian genetics. Normally, recombination rates within a gene will not be significant.

Comment: Reading a bit futher in the Wiki entry, "Mutation will have a very subtle effect on allele frequencies. Mutation rates are of the order 10−4 to 10−8, and the change in allele frequency will be, at most, the same order. Recurrent mutation will maintain alleles in the population, even if there is strong selection against them."